# Python Strategy pattern: Dynamically import class files

Tags: python, strategy-pattern, python-import

I am trying to build a software package that fixes arbitrary data inconsistencies in one of my databases. My design includes two classes - `Problem` and `Fix`.

The problems are SQL queries stored as `.cfg` files (e.g. `problem_001.cfg`), and the fixers are stored as Python files (e.g. `fix_001.py`). The query config file has a reference to the Python file name. Each fixer has a single class `Fix`, which inherits from a base class `BaseFix`.

```
`-- problems
    |-- problem_100.cfg
    |-- problem_200.cfg
    |-- problem_300.cfg
    `-- ...
`-- fixer
    |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- fixers
    |   |   |-- fix_100.py
    |   |   |-- fix_200.py
    |   |   |-- fix_300.py
    |   |   |-- ...
    |   `-- ...
    `-- ...
```

I would like to instantiate `Problem` files and supply them with `Fix` objects in a clean way. Is there a way to do it without keepping all the fixers in the same file?

**UPDATE:**

This is the final code that worked (thanks, @Space_C0wb0y):

```
    fixer_name='fix_100'
    self.fixer=__import__('fixer.fixers', globals(), locals(), 
                 [fixer_name]).__dict__[fixer_name].Fix()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically import modules using the builtin `__import__`, which takes the module-name as string-argument (see [here](http://diveintopython.net/functional_programming/dynamic_import.html)). The modules do have to be in the [module search path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).